# Java: loading in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a problem with libGDX and Android.

I want to realize loading in the AndroidApplication by Android's widgets.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
       //////////////////////
    // Create the layout
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
       layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loading_animation);
    mAnim = (AnimationDrawable)image.getBackground();

    layout.addView(image, adParams);
    setContentView(layout);

    image.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAnim.start();
        }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!MyGame.isGameLoaded) 
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    /////
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    activity_context = this;
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.hideStatusBar = true;
    config.numSamples = Utils.PrefReadInt(MainActivity.this, Utils.CARROT, Utils.SAMPLING,0) * 2;
    config.useAccelerometer = false;
    config.useCompass = false;
    config.useWakelock = true;
    config.useGL20 = true;


    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metricsB = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metricsB);
    Info.height =  metricsB.heightPixels;
    Info.width = metricsB.widthPixels;

    initialize(new MyGame(), config);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I see only black screen. I had tried to do it in other Acvitity before starting AndroidApplication, it had worked, but I couldn't check if game loaded or not.

Comment: What do you want to load? If you want to display a loadingscreen, while your game loads all the assets you are using, you can take a look at the `AssetManager`

Comment: I'd also go with Springrbua's advice and do it the "LibGDX" way...